# Codeigniter - Disallowed Key Characters when sending XML in RESTful server

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, rest

I'm implementing a REST server with codeigniter and it includes a function where some XML will be posted to retrieve some data.

The XML is passed through the body of the request and retrieved with:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

The XML is then validated by this:

```
try
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
    $doc->loadXML($xml);
    if ($doc->schemaValidate(APPPATH.'views/xml/xmlvalidate.xsd')) {
        //--this is valid
    }
}
```

This works fine with the RESTclient in firefox, but when i use Advanced REST Client in chrome I get the "disallowed key characters" error, the offending string, as according to codeigniter, being:

```
<?xml version
```

Anyone have any idea why it only works with firefox RESTclient? I need to get down to the cause of the problem in case it might error out in use after testing goes fine.

Comment: So did anyone figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Often that CI error arises from foreign language characters (even in POST data) or linebreaks after the closing php bracket.

You can adapt your allowed characters in the CI config (application/config/config.php):

change: `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_=+-';`

into: `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_=+-<>';`

or test with an empty string : `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = ''; // anything goes`

Be aware of the security ramifications when using CI's natural url to controller mapping without filtering input.

Comment: Tried both suggestions but gives the same result. The problem doesn't stem from the settings but from a deeper function where CI cleans all variables from all request data (namely the function _clean_input_keys, called from function _clean_input_data which is called from $_POST = $this->_clean_input_data($_POST); in the _sanitize_globals() function inside Input.php.

The problem is that firstly I don't understand how the XML has anything to do with keys, as it's part of the body and should surely be the array value? Secondly, why it works fine from one program but not the other.

Comment: Yep, tried all 3 and all didn't work. The source of the problem is in the Input.php file, where the function _clean_input_keys attempts to put the XML into $_POST keys (why??).